# Is there any way to create entries in a for loop with separate variables (for accessing later)?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Just working on a personal project and was wondering if it was possible to create entries in a for loop that have their own variables so they could be accessed later. You can do something similar with radiobuttons:

```py
from tkinter import *
mydict = ["a":1, "b":2]
i = -1
var = IntVar()
for key in mydict.keys():
    i += 1
    Radiobutton(self, text = key, variable = var, value = i).grid(column = 0, sticky = W)
```

This will create a radiobutton for each key in a dictionary but they all use the same variable.
Aka something that will turn this:

```
Label(self, text = "Label 1").grid(column = 0, sticky = W)
Entry(self, textvariable = entryOne).grid(column = 1, sticky = W)
Label(self, text = "").grid()

Label(self, text = "Label 2").grid(column = 0, sticky = W)
Entry(self, textvariable = entryTwo).grid(column = 1, sticky = W)
Label(self, text = "").grid()
```

into a for loop so it could be used for x times.

Comment: A variable for same group of radiobuttons is normal design.

Comment: In your code, the radiobuttons will not use the same value.

Comment: Yea, it was simple typo, I meant to say they'd all have the same variable.